# typescript-language-server does not seem to provide keyword as a semantic token type

Tags: typescript, language-server-protocol, typescript-language-server

When running typescript-language-server very basically like `typescript-language-server --stdio` I get the following `legend` back for the initialization response:

```json
{
  "tokenTypes": [
    "class",
    "enum",
    "interface",
    "namespace",
    "typeParameter",
    "type",
    "parameter",
    "variable",
    "enumMember",
    "property",
    "function",
    "member"
  ],
  "tokenModifiers": [
    "declaration",
    "static",
    "async",
    "readonly",
    "defaultLibrary",
    "local"
  ]
}
```

What is missing, for example, is the `keyword` token type. I looked at https://github.com/typescript-language-server/typescript-language-server/blob/master/docs/configuration.md but did not find a hint whether I need to activate additional token types explicitly.

Any idea why these and other token types are not reported. Is that left to vscode?